# jquery, how to loop through complex array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I did an ajax and returned an multi-dimensional array that is 5 level deep and each level have many items. I want to loop through each level and create a HTML syntax. After all level 5 is done. I will join all the syntax and append the entire list into HTML.

right now I am concerned about how to loop it correct it.

the array structure is like below

```
var array = [object, object, object, object]
            |0 object level 1
              |1 object level 2
                |0 object level 3
                  |0 object level 4
                    |0 object level 5
            |1 object
            |2 object 
            |3 object
```

here is a simplified sample data

```
var test = [
    {
        "someid":"25",
        "level1":[
            {
                "name":"john doe",
            }
            "level2": [
            {
                "order_quantity":"1",
                "order_price":"12.00",
                "level3":[
                {
                    "addon_price":"2.00"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

I try to use javascript for loop but after 2nd level it becomes very ugly and hard to track.

first level loop

```
for(i=0; i<array.length;i++)
```

second level loop

```
for(n=0; n<array[i].level1.length;n++)
```

Third level loop

```
for(y=0;y<array[i].level2[n].level3.length;y++)
```

I dont think this is the right way.

What would be the right way to loop through an array like this

I also have jquery. but not sure how to use $.each to do this either.

so jquery solution is welcome.

Comment: please add a sample of your array.

Comment: If you need to hit every element, then a 5 dimensional array is probably going to be nasty no matter how you use it.

Comment: Take a step back-is there a way to get less nested data structure? Is it possible to be more specific in your ajax request to return more flat data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach.

```js
var array = [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [[5, 6]]], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]];

array.forEach(function iter(a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        a.forEach(iter);
        return;
    }
    console.log(a);
});
```

Or use a hard coded solution

```js
var test = [{ someid: "25", level1: [{ name: "john doe", level2: [{ order_quantity: "1", order_price: "12.00", level3: [{ addon_price: "2.00" }] }] }] }];

test.forEach(function (a) {
    a.level1.forEach(function (b) {
        b.level2.forEach(function (c) {
            c.level3.forEach(function (d) {
                console.log(d.addon_price);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Or use a more dynamic solution, if the sub levels follows the same building rule.

```js
var test = [{ someid: "25", level1: [{ name: "john doe", level2: [{ order_quantity: "1", order_price: "12.00", level3: [{ addon_price: "2.00" }] }] }] }];

test.forEach(function iter(level) {
    return function (a) {
        if (Array.isArray(a['level' + level])) {
            a['level' + level].forEach(iter(level + 1));
            return;
        }
        Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
            console.log(a[k]);
        });
    }
}(1));
```

Comment: Would this work if there are an array of objects vs an array of arrays? e.g. The OP looks like he has an array of objects. Your solution looks like it deals with an array of arrays.

Comment: right, i was asking about some data of the op, to tackle the problem, but an iterative approach could help as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I just added a 3 level sample data. basic idea is that. I think if I can do 3 level, I would be able to get a good idea.

Comment: I think this might be the answer, its looking very promising and super easy to use. I will try it out with the full data and report back.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks Nina, this worked great. very clean to look at and figure out what is going on.